# Most readable and efficient way to handle ReactJS form data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I'm looking for the most **easy to read** and **efficient** way to handle my inputs from a ReactJS/Material UI form.

```js
const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState()
const [lastName, setLastName] = useState()

const handleSave = () => {
    sendToApi(firstName, lastName)  // Some function to send data to some API 
}

...

return (
<TextField
  id="first_name"
  label="First name"
  onChange={(event) => {
    setFirstName(event.target.value)
  }} />
)
```

This is how I've been handling inputs with Material UI.  But this can be an issue if you have many fields because you have to make a state for each one and the parameters for `sendToApi()` will be ever expanding.

I've also tried to use a `Set()` to eliminate duplicate changes to a field and only send the changed fields to the API.

Comment: wrap all your inputs inside form tag. use useRef on form and you can get each input value from formRef. all your inputs must have a unique name attribute.